# Inject input events to Linux GUI programs

Tags: linux, user-interface, inject

Is there any way to inject input events (e.g., keyboard inputs) to Linux GUI programs? One application of this feature is to implement system-wide shortcuts. For example, I'm using my browser to stream music, and I want to skip to the next item when I'm doing something else (e.g., writing code in vim).

Answer (score 2):

In theory you might use [XSendEvent](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSendEvent.html), but the receiving application might notice that it is fake, because the [XKeyEvent](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html#XKeyEvent) data type has a `send_event` field which is set by the [X11 server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), and the X11 clients (notably the Qt or GTK toolkits) may test it (and probably do test it).

See also [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/).

Comment: What do you mean by "fake"? Do you mean that we still need to modify/extend the receiving application to implement any useful functionality?